# Self Viewcontroller is hiding under layer ofAvplayerviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, avplayerviewcontroller

I am facing a problem with `AvPlayerViewController`.
After video ends playing, I remove `PlayerViewController` and call Adcolony's adrequest, which start playing videoAd on Self `ViewController`, but the problem is I am only able to hear audio of the ad, but the ad itself isn't visible, it seems like it's hiding under some layer.

Code to play video with AVPlayerViewController

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:videoURL];

    _player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
    _playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
    _playerViewController.player = _player;

    _player.rate = self.lastBitRate;
    _player.volume = 0.5;
    [_player playImmediatelyAtRate:self.lastBitRate];

     _playerViewController.view.frame = _viewIntro.bounds;
   // playerViewController.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

    _playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
    _playerViewController.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback=YES;
    [self.view addSubview:_playerViewController.view];
    [_player play];
```

When i try to play video on `AVPlayerLayer` then VideoAds are visible properly.

Code to playVideo with AVPlayerLayer

```
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];
        AVPlayerItem *item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
        _player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:item];
        _player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
        _avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:_player];
        _avPlayerLayer.frame = _viewIntro.bounds;    [self.view.layer addSublayer:_avPlayerLayer];
        _avPlayerLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
        //layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
        [_avPlayerLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
        [player play];
```

I try to remove `AvplayerViewController` with all methods ,i found, but no success, Ad is not presenting on top.

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self.playerViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.playerViewController removeFromParentViewController];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:nil];
```

code to show Ads

```
[AdColony requestInterstitialInZone:kAdColonyZoneID options:nil

                                success:^(AdColonyInterstitial* ad) {
                                    ad.open = ^{
                                        NSLog(@"Ad opened");

                                    };
                                    ad.close = ^{
                                        NSLog(@"Ad closed");
                                    };

                                    _ad = ad;
                                    [_ad showWithPresentingViewController:self];
                                }
                                failure:^(AdColonyAdRequestError* error) {
                                    NSLog(@"Interstitial request failed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                }
     ];
```

help me to sort out this.

Comment: please, share code how do you show the ad

Comment: Look into the zPosition of your views' layers. Maybe that will sort things out.

Comment: ok, now please share how do you insert the playerViewController in your viewController

Comment: if you avoid playing video and call the ad insertion, do you see the ad? just to understand if problem is related to the video view controller

Comment: Yes,at that time ad play perfectly

Answer (score 0):

**New Solution**

try not to dismiss `_playerViewController` and then changing the statement below

```
[_ad showWithPresentingViewController:self];
```

with this one

```
[_ad showWithPresentingViewController:_playerViewController];
```

Finally  you can dismiss `_playerViewController` after ad visualization

**Old Solution (not working)**

you should presenting the `AVPlayerViewController` instead of inserting its view in the current viewController's view, just as below

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:videoURL];

_player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
_playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
_playerViewController.player = _player;

_player.rate = self.lastBitRate;
_player.volume = 0.5;
[_player playImmediatelyAtRate:self.lastBitRate];

 _playerViewController.view.frame = _viewIntro.bounds;
//playerViewController.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

_playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
_playerViewController.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback=YES;
//[self.view addSubview:_playerViewController.view];
[self presentViewController:sideViewController animated:YES completion:^{
    [_player play];
}];
```

then, to dismiss the `_playerViewController` and show the ad, you can do as below:

```
[_playerViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:nil];
    [AdColony requestInterstitialInZone:kAdColonyZoneID options:nil

                            success:^(AdColonyInterstitial* ad) {
                                ad.open = ^{
                                    NSLog(@"Ad opened");

                                };
                                ad.close = ^{
                                    NSLog(@"Ad closed");
                                };

                                _ad = ad;
                                [_ad showWithPresentingViewController:self];
                            }
                            failure:^(AdColonyAdRequestError* error) {
                                NSLog(@"Interstitial request failed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                            }
    ];
}];
```

Comment: Hi @ddb thanks for your answer ,but this change also not work, still ad controller is not coming to top

Comment: @fin.sw, I added new solution, try it please :)

Comment: i have already try this ,even i try to show it on  navigationController ,but nothing helps me ;(

Comment: @fin.sw, but after you exec `[_playerViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`, do you see again the previous (self) viewController's view?

Comment: Yes,after  exec  [_playerViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; ,it is removed and i am able to see my other views